# How to slow a python program down

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm new to python, so I;m currently trying random stuff out, such as:

```
while True:
    print('Hello', end = ' ')
```

And I was wondering how to slow the program down, so that spamming a 'Hello' is actually perceptible. 
I have already tried the time.sleep function, but running it results in nothing but a blinking cursor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `time` package, `from time import sleep` so you can use that as:

```py
from time import sleep

while True:
    print('Hello', end = ' ', flush=True) # Thanks to @Sniggerfardimungus
    sleep(1) # Sleeps every 1 second
```

Comment: Just tried, but when I ran it I just got a blinking cursor.

Comment: @JaggyYako i've edited the answer

Comment: change that print to include flush=True. The problem is that the output is being buffered until it is either full or it sees an end-of-line, which has been removed by the end=' '.

Comment: It worked! Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: @JaggyYako, You're welcome